# Why does my XAMPP control panel crash every time I stop apache?

Tags: xampp

I am trying to enable some extensions in my php.  If I want to initiate the changes I have to reset the apache server in XAMPP.  But I just keep getting a window that says xampp-control.exe has stopped working and gives me options:

- Debug Program
- Close Program
- Check Online for a Solution and Close Program

No matter which option I choose it will then give me this Application Error:

> > Exception EAccess in modele 'xampp-control.exe' at 001ABEFE.  Access Violation at address 005ABEFE in module 'xampp-control.exe'. Read of address 00000042.

I have read that I should just install a WAMPP server.  Is there a way I can successfully reset the Apache Server?

Comment: Do you have the most recent update of xampp?

Comment: I do have the latest version of XAMPP.

Comment: It has started for me now. I hate to re install it now...

Answer (score 1):

Possible workarounds are listed on XAMPP's forum [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=270362&sid=f6bf0e49f74954bdb379cb5cbd8fd9c7)

> There are some possible workarounds:

- Enable back the write privileges and to be aware of this potential issue
- Modify the ini file with an editor the properties you need or
- To run the XAMP Control panel as administrator

Running it as administrator worked for me.